# Terminal problems: [master] tag showing in weird place

Tags: git, terminal

I'm new to CLI, and have encountered a problem. In my Users/jacobcrofts directory, the [master] tag is showing. How do I remove it? I am not working on any repositories in this location nor do I recall placing any directories here. When I ls, the only folder in the directory that was not there automatically is the folder in which I store all of my Git repos.

If this matters: when I type git status, I get a massive list of all my Chrome caches, images I've stored on my desktop, and other stuff that (seemingly?) should be here.

Comment: It sounds like you've made a git repository of your home directory. If you run `ls -al .git` does it return anything?

Comment: @AlVaz yes, here's what is says: http://prntscr.com/8oyuy4

Comment: Yes, so it seems that Users/jacobrofts was accidentally made a git repository. Adding an answer now. If it works, please accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your answer to my question in the comments, it appears you accidentally ran `git init` while in /Users/jacobcrofts. I assume you didn't intend to make a git repository out of your entire home directory. In that case, the simple fix is to simply `rm -rf /Users/jacobcrofts/.git` to remove the .git directory from your home directory and your issue should go away.